# numpy.savetxt save array to a specific location in file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `file.txt` of the form:

```
; In this topology include file, you will find position restraint
; entries for all the heavy atoms in your original pdb file.
; This means that all the protons which were added by pdb2gmx are
; not restrained.

[ position_restraints ]
; atom  type      fx      fy      fz
     1     1  1000  1000  1000
     5     1  1000  1000  1000
     7     1  1000  1000  1000
    10     1  1000  1000  1000
    12     1  1000  1000  1000
    13     1  1000  1000  1000
    14     1  1000  1000  1000
    16     1  1000  1000  1000
```

(If you are interested, this is a position restrain file from [gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org/))

In Python, I have a numpy.array of integers `[2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 108]`. I want to replace `file.txt` with:

```
; In this topology include file, you will find position restraint
; entries for all the heavy atoms in your original pdb file.
; This means that all the protons which were added by pdb2gmx are
; not restrained.

[ position_restraints ]
; atom  type      fx      fy      fz
     2     1  1000  1000  1000
     4     1  1000  1000  1000
     7     1  1000  1000  1000
     8     1  1000  1000  1000
     9     1  1000  1000  1000
    10     1  1000  1000  1000
    15     1  1000  1000  1000
   108     1  1000  1000  1000
```

That is, the first column of the table inside `file.txt` will be replaced by the integer array I defined in Python. Please, note how the alignment in the column is respected. This is important.

How can I do this? I used `numpy.savetxt` in the question title because it is close to what I want to do, but I don't think `numpy.savetxt` by itself will be able to do it.

How can I do this?

Comment: how is it delimited?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able recreate this output using `savetxt` and various parameters.

It takes `header` and `comments`.  I'd try a multiline header, and `comments=';'` and see if reproduces your file header.

`fmt` controls the layout of the data.  You can specify one column, and it will replicate that for all, or you can specify all columns.  Look at the docs and play around.

As for the data, I'd load it from the original file, getting a 2d array (it's all integers).  Then replace the 1st column with the new numbers. And pass it to your `savetxt`.

Roughly:

```
arr = loadtxt('oldfile', etc)
arr[:,0] = newcolumn
np.savetxt('newfile', arr, header..., )
```

Another approach to the header is to read the appropriate lines from the original, and write them to a new file.  Then leaving the file open, pass its handle to the `savetxt`.  `savetxt` takes either a filename, or the handle of an already open file.  So it can add material to an existing file.

Failing that you could write your own file.  `savetxt` isn't doing anything mysterious.  It's all there in the python code.  The core step for writing the data is:

```
 for row in X:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

In other words, it writes the 2d array, row by row, line by line.  `format` is derived from your input `fmt` parameter.

```
 format % tuple(row)
```

is the just normal Python string formatting, using the data from one row of your input array.  Experiment with `fmt` till you get the right column layout.